# Could not find function "describe" (doing descriptive stats analysis)

Tags: r

I'm getting the following error message when attempting descriptive statistical analysis...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(
                   row.names = c("Mazda RX4",
                                 "Mazda RX4 Wag","Datsun 710",
                                 "Hornet 4 Drive","Hornet Sportabout","Valiant",
                                 "Duster 360","Merc 240D"),
         mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4),
         cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4),
          hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62)
                )
#>                    mpg cyl  hp
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6 110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 110
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  93
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 110
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 175
#> Valiant           18.1   6 105
#> Duster 360        14.3   8 245
#> Merc 240D         24.4   4  62

describe(mtcars,
         mean_mpg = mean(mpg),
         sd_mpg = sd(mpg))
#> Error in describe(mtcars, mean_mpg = mean(mpg), sd_mpg = sd(mpg)): could not find function "describe"
```

How do I solves this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
library(psych)
describe(mtcars)
Gives below description as shown
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as `describe` in (base) R.
Perhaps you are looking for `summarise` from `dplyr`?

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg), sd_mpg = sd(mpg))

#>   mean_mpg   sd_mpg
#> 1 20.09062 6.026948
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>